# internet explorer mode rewrite

Tags: css, image, .htaccess

I have website with the following structure

/

/projects

my htaccess is placed at the / folder with the following rules

```
RewriteBase /projects/  
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^projects/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/$ /projects/index.php?location=$1&title=$2 [L]
AddType video/ogg .ogv
AddType video/mp4 .mp4
AddType video/webm .webm
```

I am expecting to have url like this :

```
http://www.domain.com/projects/location/title
```

however my problem is that the css and js files also loaded in IE9 this way
domain.com/projects/location/title/css.file
domain.com/projects/location/title/js.file
and the images folder as well

I am using absolute pass  and it works for chrome and firefox
but still not in IE.

Could anyone help in this ?

EDIT
iam using 
but still IE is causing the problem

Answer (score 0):

If placed in document root then have this code in your .htaccess:

```
AddType video/ogg .ogv
AddType video/mp4 .mp4
AddType video/webm .webm

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^projects/([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)/?$ /projects/index.php?location=$1&title=$2 [L,QSA]
```

`RewriteBase /projects/` is needed only when it is placed in `/projects/.htaccess`.

Comment: thanks for the note however this did not solve the main problem :)

Comment: Open your page in Firebug and tell me which css/js URL is causing 404?

Comment: actually as i mentioned it works fine for chrome and Firfox after using the <base> Tag but it still load wrong urls in IE9 , example : http://domain.com/location/title/cssfolder/cssfile which doesn't really exist the same goes for all images and javascript files too in IE9 only i didn't try it on other versions however i believe the problem will remain

Comment: ok i noticed that it load at the beging and then being redirected

Comment: no , it load properly in the begging then somehow the rule is applied and ruin it again

Comment: Didn't understand your comment. Can you clarify?

Comment: this is an example for this image op.jpg ,at the begging it loaded normally 200 status ,http://127.0.0.1/projects/images/backgrounds/op.jpg this is the proper pass , then /projects/west-cairo/october-park/images/backgrounds/op.jpg ( this is the rewritten url )